# Setting image for i3-lock: "Could not load image x: out of memory"

Tags: linux, images, tiling-wm

I use this command for locking screen:

```
i3lock -i /home/freyja/pics/owl.jpg
```

The screen is locked, but there is no picture (only white background).
When called from console the command says:

```
Could not load image /home/freyja/pics/owl.jpg: out of memory.
```

What can I do about this? Is memory lacking in whole system (does not seem like it) or just i3-lock has some internal restriction? The picture is big (HD), but the resolution exactly matches my screen, so I wouldn't like to use a smaller one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution was to convert image to PNG (thought you would think that for a photo it would actually take more memory, so maybe the error message wasn't very accurate).

I found the solution here: http://archive.rebeccablacktech.com/g/thread/44391920#p44393721

But I thought it would be good if the answer could be also found on a bit more... focused place.

Comment: I have the same problem but also with *.png files iirc. What's the size of the *.png you're now using?

Comment: @DaedalusMythos 

resolution: `identify owl.png: owl.png PNG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.076MB 0.000u 0:00.000` disc size: `du -b owl.png : 2076394 owl.png`

Comment: thanks man. I think my problem was that the file suffix was incorrectly named png.